# Handling "Before you continute to Google" pop-up in Chrome browser using Appium

Tags: python, android, appium

When I open a https://google.com page on my Android device using Appium server there is pop-up informing about cookies stuff. Is there way to handle it automatically? Because the only way I have found is to double click read more button and then accept it manually and I don't think it is the most efficent solution.

Also I used sleep() method to wait between doubleclicking the read more button. Should an additional function be created or also there is built-in method to handle similar cases?

[image: pop-up]

Here is my code:

```py
import time

from appium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

desired_caps = dict(

    deviceName='Android',
    automationName='uiautomator2',
    platformName='Android',
    browserName='Chrome',
    autoAcceptAlerts=True,
)

driver = webdriver.Remote('127.0.0.1:4723', desired_caps)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://google.com")
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="QS5gu SSSe5e"]')))

element.click()
time.sleep(2)
element.click()

accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="QS5gu sy4vM"]')))
accept_button.click()

search_bar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@name="q"]')))
search_bar.send_keys("Hello world!")

print(driver.title)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting desired capability `appium:autoGrantPermissions` to true.
I am not sure if it will work for chrome, I use this for a native app and works perfectly.

documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#app)

Edit: I researched a little bit more, from my understanding this capability can only be used for native apps and there is no alternative for Chrome. What I would suggest is to export this to a different method e.g `acceptCokies` and call this method instead, whenever necessary.